# Javascript efficiently get row number of a value in two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, search, multidimensional-array

What is the most efficient way to return the row number of a value in a two-dimensional array? For example, I could do the following. Can I do it using map and/or filter instead of iteration?

```
function getRow(array2d = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']], value = 'g') {
  for (let i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++) {
    if (array2d[i].indexOf(value) > -1) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: How your doing it is fine, using map / filter may even make it less efficient due to callback overhead.  You could maybe change `indexOf` to `includes(value)`, that might be a little faster as it then doesn't need to do the -1 compare.

Comment: I guess it depends if the arrays can contain duplicate values. If not you have check each value one by one anyway. Otherwise you could use Set first to remove noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like this:

```js
function getRow(array2d = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']], value = 'g') {
  for (let i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++) {
    if (array2d[i].indexOf(value) > -1) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

const now = performance.now();
console.log(getRow());
console.log(performance.now() - now);
```

```js
function getRow(array2d = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']], value = 'g') {
  return array2d.findIndex(x => x.includes(value));
}

const now = performance.now();
console.log(getRow());
console.log(performance.now() - now);
```

Comment: If `most efficient way`,  was meaning less code, then this is fine.  On the other hand if speed is what the OP means, then this is slower.

Comment: What makes you state that?

Comment: State what?..  It's slower, than what the OP already had, so how is this the most efficient way?

Comment: State that this is slower

Comment: I am looking for faster, but thank you for the alternative.

Comment: @Keith I'm expecting you to demonstrate what you state. `performance.now` doesn't show any obvious difference and this benchmark shows that findIndex is faster: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/9342/0/object-arrays-findindex-vs-for-loop#latest_results_block I got 991 ops/sec with `findIndex` and 380 ops/sec with the `for` loop on my machine under Chromium

Comment: A couple of tips for testing performance.  1, don't do a single pass, otherwise your timing parser performance, eg. try putting the OP's code into 1 single line.   Instead try doing this instead -> `for (let l = 0; l < 100000; l += 1) getRow()`

Comment: Testing in Google Apps Script, where I'm applying it, include was faster than the for loop.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Posting example here of `findIndex` with callback been slower than `for loop`..

Results for me:

for loop = `11.020000092685223`  faster.

findIndex with callback = `12.699999962933362`  slower.

The morale of the story, if performance is critical always test.  Browsers have some very clever / complicated optimisation.  For example the benchmark posted by @GuerricP only did a simple property comparison and the V8 engine possible detects this.  Place a more complicated `includes` inside, and it's a different story.

It's also for the above reason you should never pre-optimise JS, only optimise when you believe you have a performance issue to solve.

Also to complicate matter different Browsers / OS's will likely give different results.  My tests where Linux / Chrome.

```js
function getRow(array2d = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']], value = 'g') {
  for (let i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++) if (array2d[i].indexOf(value) > -1) return i;
  return -1;
}

const now = performance.now();
for (let l = 0; l < 1000000; l += 1)
  getRow();
console.log(performance.now() - now);
```

```js
function getRow(array2d = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']], value = 'g') {
  return array2d.findIndex(x => x.includes(value));
}

const now = performance.now();
for (let l = 0; l < 1000000; l += 1)
  getRow();
console.log(performance.now() - now);
```

Answer (score 1):

With nodes, you can divide the array into multiple
sub-arrays and use async to run the search in parallel:

The following script uses two threads and will give you half of the time.

```js
async function aGetRow(d, v) {
  let half = Math.floor(d.length / 2);
  let remain = d.length - half
  let r = await Promise.all([
    getRow(d.slice(0, half), v),
    getRow(d.slice(half, remain), v),
  ]);
  if (r[0] != -1) {
    return r[0];
  }
  if (r[1] != -1) {
    return r[1];
  }
  return -1;
}
```

One must note that NodeJS has 4 threads in the thread pool by default. If you split the array more than the threads, you will not gain performance enhancement.

Edit: For people interested in the details of NodeJS threading and event loop, I highly recommend this video: https://youtu.be/zphcsoSJMvM